# SwiftでのHTTP GETの非同期処理の書き方がわかりません。

Tags: swift, http

## 質問

Swift での`HTTP GET`の「非同期処理」の書き方がわかりません。

### やりたいこと

APIにアクセスして、データをダウンロードできたタイミングでTextに表示させたいです。

`httpGet()`で取得した`Data()`を戻り値としたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

### エラー

Voidのクロージャーの中で`return data`しており、そのエラーが出ています。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

**ソースコード:**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class API {
    public static func httpGet(_ urlString: String) -> Data?{
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            return data;
        })
        
        task.resume()
        
        return nil
    }
    
}

class SampleAPI : API{
    public static func getData() -> String? {
        let urlString = "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/"
                
        if let data = super.httpGet(urlString) {
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            return dataString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text: String = "Hello"
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.showData()
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func showData() {
        if let text = SampleAPI.getData() {
            print(text)
            self.text = text
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Swift でのHTTP GETの「非同期処理」の書き方がわかりません。

最も一般的なのは、自前の完了ハンドラを導入する形でしょう。

こんな感じになります。

```
import SwiftUI

class API {
    public static func httpGet(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping(Data?)->Void){
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            completion(data)
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }
}

class SampleAPI : API{
    public static func getData(completion: @escaping(String?)->Void) {
        let urlString = "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/"
        
        super.httpGet(urlString) { data in
            if let data = data,
               let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                completion(dataString)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text: String = "Hello"
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.showData()
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func showData() {
        SampleAPI.getData { text in
            if let text = text {
                print(text)
                self.text = text
            } else {
                print("Got nil")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

完了ハンドラを使うパターンは、ほんの少し発想を変え、呼び出し方法も変えないといけないので、最初は大変難しく感じられるかもしれませんが、慣れれば書き換えはそれほど大変ではなく、何よりも現時点では最も一般的な方法と言えるでしょう。

---

もしSwift5.5(Xcode 13)を使用することができる(今の所ターゲットをiOS15世代以降にする必要がある)なら、Swift 5.5で導入されたasync/awaitを使うのが簡単でしょう。まだ時期尚早かと思うので、ここには詳しくは書きませんが、beta版のXcode 13を導入済みなら、色々試してみられると良いでしょう。

Comment: この方法だと完了ハンドラが２重になっていると思うのですが、なんとなく冗長のような気がするのですが、それは気にする必要ないですかね？

Comment: @zunda さん、 `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`でも完了ハンドラが使われているから三重ですね。それが冗長だと感じられて嫌ならそもそも、「なぜ`httpGet`と`getData`を別に定義するの?」という点に目をやるべきでしょう。適切なメソッド分割をしてメソッド呼び出しが「二重」になるのを気にする必要がないのと同様に、完了ハンドラが二重になるのも気にする必要はありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにそうですね。
async/awaitを少し調べてみたところ、こういった冗長性がasync/awaitで解消されるのでしょうか？
https://qiita.com/koher/items/29357b5e00aec1962601

Comment: @zunda さん、その通りです。引用された記事はSwiftのasync/awaitよりも、JavaScriptではかなりお馴染みになったPromiseの方の記述が長い気がします。今回ご質問されたようなコードをasync/awaitに落とし込むのは極めて簡単で、直感通りに処理の結果は戻り値にすれば良いですし、非同期かどうかはあまり気にせずに処理の順番にコードを記述すれば良い、ただし時々async/awaitなんてキーワードを挟むこと、といった感じで済みます。(Swiftのasync/awaitについて書いてくれている記事を見つけた方がわかりやすいと思います。例によって日本語の良い記事があるかどうかは知らないんですが…。)Xcode 13 が使えるなら試してみて、わからない点をご質問していただければと思います。

Answer (score -1):

２つの方法があります。

一つ目は、完了ハンドラーのクロージャーがあるクラスに、`view`を弱参照で持ち、完了ハンドラーの中でプロパティを書き替える方法。非同期処理的にはこちらがより理想的な回答だと思います。

ソースにするとこんな感じになります。
書き替えたいプロパティをメンバーに持たずに、引数で渡されたインスタンスのプロパティを書き替える形にするとより良いかもしれません。

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class API {
    weak var view: ContentView

    public static func httpGet(_ urlString: String) -> Data?{
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            // data を textに変換
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

            // textをviewにセット
            view.text = dataString
        })
        
        task.resume()
        
        return nil
    }
    
}

class SampleAPI : API{

    public static func getData() -> String? {
        let urlString = "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/"
                
        if let data = super.httpGet(urlString) {
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            return dataString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text: String = "Hello"
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.showData()
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func showData() {
        let api = SampleAPI()
        api.view = self
        if let text = api.getData() {
            print(text)
            self.text = text
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

もう一つはセマフォアを使って、`API`クラスの完了ハンドラーが完了するまでリターンするのを待つ方法です。

この方法は非同期処理を同期的に待つ事になるので、行っていることのトレースは楽ですが、非同期処理を行っているという思想的にはあまりお勧め出来ません。

サンプルはこんな感じです

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class API {
    public static func httpGet(_ urlString: String) -> Data? {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        var text = ""
        let semahpore: DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard { semaphore.signal() }
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        })
        
        task.resume()
        let timeout = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now + .second(20))
        
        if timeout == .success {
            return text
        } else {
            returan "failed"
        }
    }
    
}

class SampleAPI : API{
    public static func getData() -> String? {
        let urlString = "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/"
                
        if let data = super.httpGet(urlString) {
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            return dataString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text: String = "Hello"
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.text)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    self.showData()
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func showData() {
        if let text = SampleAPI.getData() {
            print(text)
            self.text = text
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: セマフォについては、メインスレッドを待たせることになるので「思想的にはあまりお勧め出来ません」ではなく、**絶対にやってはいけない** に属することでしょう。App Storeのレビューでどこまでテストされるかわかりませんが、それだけでリジェクトされる理由になり得ます。